# How on click rerender conmponent in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

When I click on a card, the loadAboutInfo function works through which I transfer data to another component and display it there. But if I click again on the same card, then it is duplicated. How can I fix it?I have check which take card id and then if it the same it render but I click again it render one more card, but i need if it already exist than new card mustn't render

```
loadAboutInfo=(pokemonValue,pockemonImg,pokemonId)=>{
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                pokemonValue:[...prevState.pokemonValue, pokemonValue],
                pockemonImg,
                pokemonId
            }))
        }

    render() {
        return (                    
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="pokemonlist__inner__cards">
                    <div className="pokemonlist__cards">
                        {this.state.pokemonList.map((value,index)=>{
                            let pokemonImgTemplate = this.state.pokemonImgTemplate;
                            let pokemonId = value.id;
                            let pockemonImg = pokemonImgTemplate.replace('{id}',pokemonId);
                            return(
                                <div className="pokemonListCard" key={index} onClick={()=>this.loadAboutInfo(value,pockemonImg,pokemonId)}>
                                        <PokemonCard 
                                            pockemonImg={pockemonImg}
                                            pokemonName={value.name}
                                            pokemonTypes={value.types}
                                        />
                            </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <PokemonLoadMore 
                        loadMore={this.loadMore}
                        currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

component where i map get data

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="pokemon__about">
                {this.props.pokemonValue.map((value,index)=>{
                   let totalMoves = value.moves.length;
                    return(
                        <div className="pokemon__about__wrapper" key={index}>
                            {this.props.pokemonId == value.id ?
                                <div className="pokemon__about__inner" key={index}>
                                    <AboutImage 
                                        pockemonImg={this.props.pockemonImg}
                                    />
                                    <AboutName
                                        pockemonName={value.name}
                                    />
                                    <div className="pokemon__about__table">
                                            <AboutPokemonTypes 
                                                pokemonTypes={value.types}
                                                />
                                                <table>
                                            <AboutPokemonWeight 
                                                pockemonWeight={value.weight}
                                            />
                                            <AboutPokemonMoves 
                                                totalMoves={totalMoves}
                                            />
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                :
                                null
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

On the `loadAboutInfo` you can check if there is already a pokemon with the same id on `pokemonValue` array, something like this:

```
loadAboutInfo = (pokemonValue,pockemonImg,pokemonId) => {
    // this will get the first element that matches the id
    const exists = this.state.pokemonValue.find(pokemon => pokemon.id === pokemonId)

    if (!exists) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            pokemonValue:[...prevState.pokemonValue, pokemonValue],
            pockemonImg,
            pokemonId
        }))
    }
}
```

So it will update the state only if the clicked pokemon isn't in the `pokemonValue` array